# Cannot find module '@rails/ujs' - Rails 6 Webpack App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-ujs

I have these errors in a Rails 6 app and all javascript is not working:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@rails/activestorage' in '/Users/jrsahuquillo/Dropbox/myappname/app/javascript/packs'
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 9:0-31

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@rails/ujs' in '/Users/jrsahuquillo/Dropbox/myappname/app/javascript/packs'
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:0-21
```

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "myappname",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.2",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.2",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "2.1.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

In `application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
```

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

It was working ok, but I don´t know when and why it left working.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but did you run a `yarn install`? Have you tried to remove your `node_modules` and run again `yarn install`?
Like that, everything looks good in the setup rails to me.

Comment: @beauraF yes, i tried it, but it still is not working. Thanks. Any other idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I solved it yet. Previously to having the error, I installed `yarn autoclean`, and I discovered later that in `.yarnclean` there was this:

```
# asset directories
docs
doc
website
images
assets
```

I removed this, and error disappeared.

Comment: I had installed for months, but got the error suddenly. It was this, I would never know.

Comment: yeah this also fixed my issue as well. I absent mindly added yarn clean and it caused me hours of headache with @rails/ujs not found

Answer (score 3):

Run the commands. the node_modules has a problem i guess.

```
yarn add rails-ujs turbolinks
npm install rails-ujs turbolinks
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error when running system tests and managed to fix it by removing node_modules folder and anything that was cached in /tmp folder and then reran `yarn install`.

Cause of the issue for me was:

Had recently ran `yarn autoclean --init` `yarn autoclean --force` and then tried to reverse it since everything was messed up.