# Application.js can't find @rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm updating a fairly old project to rails 6, and adapt to current "rails ways". And I've just installed webpacker, but I've run into problem I can't seem to find a way to solve.

When running the project, I get this error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@rails/ujs'`

I've tried to reinstall rails-ujs through yarn, but to no effect.

Also I've tried to comment the line `require("@rails/ujs").start()` from my **app/javascript/packs/application.js**, and yet I got another error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@rails/activestorage'`.

Which leads me to believe that its the global **@rails** that is not being recognized, however I have no idea where is it set or how to do so.

My questions are:
Can I set **@rails** myself?

Is there a way to re-generate it?

or

Is there another configuration I should fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module '@rails/ujs' - Rails 6 Webpack App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344632/cannot-find-module-rails-ujs-rails-6-webpack-app)

Answer (score 0):

It’s not @rails which is missing, it’s the ujs (and active storage) JavaScript packages which are missing.

Run `yarn install` To install them.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion, but I rave already run  ```yarn install```, also i've seen the question you mentioned on the other comment and tried it's sugestions, but still not working